# How does HashTable Order Values?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

I want to know how hashtable orders its values after using Put method.

For example:

```
a         b           c       d                   e
Normal    2 weeks     Next    Save and Finish     Go to Cases
```

hashtable.put("a","Normal"); ...

The order of the values will be different and not in the same order we put.
I think the order will be like this:

```
b         a        e              c         d                     
2 weeks   Normal   Go to Cases    Next      Save and Finish
```

Please suggest data structures that solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: `HashTable` does not guarantee preserving insertion order. Consider [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: It orders them by putting them into a blender and then picking out each piece. (There's no order)

Comment: Accept the answer that best helped ya solving the problem or making you understand the concept, you've asked **8** question so far and accepted non!
Bro, you also encourage users to help ya by rewarding them and accepting their answers, as well as for every answer ya accept, ya gain +2.

Comment: @Yahya You use an interesting amount of slang. Greetings from Dublin.

Comment: @byxor cheers man, I just sometimes write on hurry. Greetings from Waterford though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [HashMap](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/hashing.html), [HashTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) also does not guarantee insertion order for the elements.

**Reason**
`HashTable` is optimized for fast look up. This is achieved by calculating hash for key values stored. This ensures that searching for any value in `HashTable` is O(1), takes the same time irrespective the number entries in `HashTable`.

Thus the entries are stored based on the hash generated for key. This is the reason why `HashTable` does not guarantee the order of the elements in which they were inserted.

> A hash value (or simply hash), also called a message digest, is a number generated from a string of text. The hash is substantially smaller than the text itself, and is generated by a formula in such a way that it is extremely unlikely that some other text will produce the same hash value.

http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/hashing.html
http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/Hashing.html

Comment: Thank a lot for your great answer.

Answer (score 6):

As very often in these cases, the answer is [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Answer (score 1):

As previously explained, hashtable iterate order is just casual. If you want to preserve inserted order use LinkedHashMap. If you want to obtain natural order or a predefined one, use TreeMap. As natural order I mean the order of key, for example String, Integer, Long and so on, as implement Comparable interface, are automatically sorted as any other class that implements Comparable. Predefined order can be supplied by a Comparator too, creating the TreeMap.